# Background GPS point gathering on PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I would like to build a phone gap app that has the ability to get GPS points while in the background. Is there something that is part of Cordova that works like that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the plugin [cordova-plugin-background-geolocation](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation). I have been using it on my Android and iOS apps and it integrates and works well.

It also can be easily found on a Google search.

Comment: Which is, incidentally, the second Google search result if you put the title of this question right into their search box. I'm always a little baffled that people would rather register and post a SO question than put it into Google first...